# Regular expression match a list of sub-strings but excluding a list of strings containing the sub-strings

Tags: regex

I would like to find a generic way to setup a regular  expression match a list of sub-strings but excluding a list of strings containing the sub-strings.

For example, to match ‘his | her’ but to exclude ‘her_cup | her_table | his_car | his_bike’. The lists can be more or less randomly formed.

Comment: show us wt did u try!

Comment: I am using python re.sub(). I am trying to replace some sub strings with different strings with dictionary. However some strings contain the sub strings can not be changed, as they are from 3rd party released library symbols. Those are not from the 3rd party library will be replaced.

Comment: already gave you an answer

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get to the bottom of what you want due to the lack of explanation.
from what i understand you should use this regex to bounder your pattern :

```
(?<![^\s^,^\.])(his|her)(?![^\s^,^\.])
```

**Explanation :**

```
(?<![^\s^,^\.]) --> negative look-behind (don't allow symbols other than {space, comma, dot})
(his|her) ---> your atomic words
(?![^\s^,^\.]) ---> negative look-ahead same as the first one
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yTVzEg/1)

Some [documentation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) on Regex

Answer (score 0):

What regex engine ?

Generically, this is solved by matching both lists of things wanted/un-wanted.
There are ways to craft it with assertions, but it is not generic.

If you use PCRE or Perl, you can use the backtrack verbs to *skip* the
unwanted stuff automatically.

Such as `(?:her_cup|her_table|his_car|his_bik)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?:his|her)`

https://regex101.com/r/wv7qPo/1

Otherwise, you'd have to match both in a loop and use the capture group as a
flag to see if you matched a good one.

`(?:her_cup|her_table|his_car|his_bik)|(his/her)`

The basic rule is you have to match something to move past it, otherwise
parts of the unwanted substrings could be included within the good substrings.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. The problem is solved with something like ‘r her (!?(_cup|_table).

Comment: @JunY - Yeah, but that's not a _generic way_ to do it.